# Cannot unzip inside AWS Fargate container

Tags: amazon-web-services, zlib, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have Java application that extracts content from zip archive.
When launching it as a `Fargate` task, it produces the following error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
```

I could get similar zlib error while running an app locally and setting non-writable directory to extract zip archive content to. It works otherwise.

Using various directories inside Docker layer did not help (i tried `/tmp` and `WORKDIR`, I also tried `User: root` in `ContainerDefinition`), neither did an approach with mounting writable volume in `ContainerDefinition`.
According to documentation, Fargate provides 10GB for writable upper Docker layer and 4GB for mounted volume. Why I cannot extract zip archive?

I cannot trace it further, as Fargate does not provide an option for this, and I could not get more informative Java exception.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that zip file I've tried to upload has zero buffer. I needed to add `Binary media type` support to `Api Gateway` for zip file to upload correctly to destination `Task`.